# Standard DateTime Picker in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Does anyone know whether there is a standard Time picker or datetime picker available in Visualforce framework? Visualforce Date picker is a powerful component that can be easily used with . But when we are having DataTime field, there is no way to prompt the  user to edit such a field value with a standard component.
Isn't this still available?

Thanks,
Madhura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I used a third party datetime picker as the solution since no where it's mentioned clearly about a visualforce datetime picker. I managed the datetime picker text with a `string` in the controller and used `DateTime.valueof(string)` to update my datetime field

Answer (score 9):

You can use a new & cool `apex:input` field that supports many types like `time` ([learn more](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_input.htm)). Note that the visualforce page need to have a HTML5 doc type for that.

[image]

Here is an simple example:

Apex:

```
public Date myDate { get; set; }
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="YourController" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form>
        Enter Time: 
        <apex:input type="time" value="{!myTime}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The result looks like this in Firefox 25:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mast0r . I used this and it's working in chrome(31.0) but not in FF. Tried updating into v26 also but still not working. Additionally, for a DateTime field it's not allowing me to us the type as 'time'. Instead it's asking for 'datetime-local'. Any idea?

Comment: Have you used `docType="html-5.0"`?

Comment: Yes, It is @mast0r

Comment: Seems HTML5 `<input />` is not much have the browser compatibility [check here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)