# Datetime link to insert current datetime with standard apex:inputfield not working

Tags: visualforce, datetime

I have a VF page of version 47 with lightningStylesheets as true and included apex:slds tag. I'am trying to use apex:inputfield as below but link to insert current datetime is not working.

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="slds-input"  id="StartDate" value="{!obj.StartDate__c}" />
```

Link to insert date time gets displayed but date is not inserted on click of it. Any pointers?

Comment: You should include a full copy of your Visualforce markup and the controller. Side note, `<apex:inputField` can only be used with fields on an sObject and it seems like you are referencing an object in memory `{!obj.StartDate__c}`

Comment: actually other code is irrelevant and will only add to confusion(VF page is more than 700 lines). Also , obj is a sObject.

Answer (score 1):

According to the main [apex:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) docs, it's unclear whether `inputField` can handle Datetimes:

> Read-only fields, and fields for certain Salesforce objects **with complex automatic behavior, such as Event.StartDateTime and Event.EndDateTime**, don't render as editable when using . Use a different input component such as  instead.

I'd consider using `apex:input` where `type="datetime"`, which should give you a nice datepicker as well (see an example in this [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22424/55891))